# what's the meaning of "likely unconstitutional"?

Tags: vocabulary

On the newspapers, they said that "NSA phone program likely unconstitutional."  See the link: http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/dec/16/nsa-phone-surveillance-likely-unconstitutional-judge

What's the difference between "unconstitutional" and "likely unconstitutional"? May I get the source of the term of American Law?

Comment: It just means "probably unconstitutional". I don't understand what you are asking in the last sentence?

Comment: Thank you Martin. What's the difference between normal "unconstitutional" and "probably unconstitutional"? Can I see the source (sites ) that explains the meanings of American law terminology.

Comment: What source? You want the US constitution? Or you want to know why they think it is unconstitutional? Neither seem on topic for an English language site.

Comment: Martin, is there the site about law?

Comment: The meaning of "probably" or "likely" is the same in US law as it is in any normal dictionary of the English language.

Comment: hmmm. @choster, the newspaper said that the **federal judge** rules that it is "likely unconstitutional".

Comment: @choster No. He is not yet in position to make that ruling. What he determined was that the likelihood that the program will eventually be found to be unconstitutional is great enough to permit him to grant plaintiffs the preliminary injunction for which they were praying; but he stayed that injunction pending appeal to a higher court.

Comment: @oerkelens: Collins has this usage note: '_Likely_ as an adverb is preceded by another, intensifying adverb, as in _it will very likely rain_ or _it will most likely rain_. Its use without an intensifier, as in _it will likely rain_ is regarded as unacceptable by most users of British English, though it is common in colloquial US English.' AHD has 'the unmodified use of _likely_ ... might be better avoided in highly formal style ...' Is US law considered not to use a very formal style?

Comment: This is headlinese.  Words have been left out.  It's something like this: ***The** NSA phone program **is** likely **to be** unconstitutional, **a** federal judge rules*

Comment: The judge is essentially saying that in his opinion, the NSA program is unconstitutional, and he believes any appeals have a very small probability of not endorsing this view.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, no, the use of the word here has nothing to do with the possibility of appeals. The likelihood in question is the likelihood of succeeding when the case goes to trial (the decision that the question is about is on a motion for preliminary injunction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is unconstitutional, then it goes against the rules laid down in the constitution.

If it is likely unconstitutional, someone thinks that it probably is so, but there is no official ruling about it.

Certainly a high quality newspaper will not claim things of which they are not sure, and depending on the country, decisions as to whether something is or is not constitutional can only be made by appropriate institutions, such as high or supreme courts.

As Jon Hanna correctly noted:

In this case, it was a judge who ruled the program to be "likely unconstitutional" - he did not rule on whether it actually was. He could not, or did not want to (but I guess the former) actually decide whether it was or was not unconstitutional, however, in his verdict he is quite clear that he thinks that it *is*.

Until there is an official ruling on the matter by an appropriate court, we are to understand that it may be likely that the program is unconstitutional, but it is not sure.

Comment: the term "likely unconstitutional" or "probably unconstitutional" is the official law terminology ?

Comment: And is there any stackexchange site about law issue?

Comment: This is incorrect, there was a ruling on the matter, but it was for an injunction, and it was the Court, not the paper claiming the likelihood.

Comment: @JonHanna: I would say it was incomplete, rather than incorrect, but I added the specifics for this case :)

Comment: @oerkelens He **could not** in this instance, and he was not called upon to do so.

Comment: I am wwith oerkelens on this one. An injunction is very specifically a temporary decision that lasts only until there is a full ruling, so *probable* (or 'likely' in journalese) is a fair summary, though it is not a word any Court ruling would use.

Comment: The phrase 'likely unconstitutional' seems only to have arisen in a headline and is being given far too much prominence. Judge Leon is not claimed even to use the word 'likely' in the linked article, where it is **reported** that '[he] ruled that the bulk collection of Americans’ telephone records by the National Security Agency is likely to violate the US constitution'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, no, the word is a part of the court's opinion; in fact the court, legally, **must** determine whether it is likely that the plaintiff will (eventually) succeed on the merits in order to decide whether a preliminary injunction is warranted.

Comment: @oerkelens, there is no **verdict** here.

Answer (score 1):

This trial is still in a very early stage; he ruling is on a Motion for Preliminary Injunction only. The judge has not yet been called upon to determine whether the program in question **is** unconstitutional, because the full evidence and argument are not yet before him.

What he was called upon to determine in this ruling was (*inter alia*) whether plaintiffs have ‘substantial likelihood of success on the merits’. In effect, his judicial review of the case at this point extends no farther than determining the **likelihood** that the program is unconstitutional—and that is as far as his ruling goes.

What is particularly newsworthy about this ruling is the unusually minatory language in which the judge expressed it:

> [T]he question I will ultimately have to answer when I reach the merits of this case someday is whether people have a reasonable expectation of privacy that is violated when the Government, without any basis whatsoever to suspect them of wrongdoing, collects and stores for five years their telephony metadata for purposes of subjecting it to high-tech querying and analysis without any case-by-case judicial approval. For the many reasons set forth above, it is significantly likely that on the that day, I will answer that question in plaintiff’s favor.
>   [...]
>   Given the limited record before me at this point in the litigation—most notably, the utter lack of evidence that a terrorist attack has ever been prevented because searching the NSA database was faster than other tactics—I have serious doubts about the efficacy of the metadata collections as a means of conducting time-sensitive investigations in cases involving imminent threats of terrorism. [... ] Thus, plaintiffs have a substantial likelihood of showing that their privacy interests outweigh the Government’s interest in collecting an analyzing bulk telephony metadata and therefore the NSA’s bulk collection program is indeed an unreasonable search under the Fourth Amendment.

In other words: Although it is not proper for me to rule on this now, I put the Government on notice that when it **is** proper for me to do so I probably will rule this program to be unconstitutional.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in the U.S., the process of ***judicial review*** determines the constitutionality of something. The headline claims that it's *likely unconstitutional* because if it were brought before the Supreme Court, the court would *likely* rule the NSA's actions unconstitutional (that is, not in accordance with the Constitution).

Comment: Thank you @njboot . I am not familiar with stackexchange. So I voted oerkelens's answer because his (or her) answer was the first. I appreciate your answer. Now, I will search the "judicial review"

Comment: You're welcome. Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutionality

Comment: Thank you. @njboot. Do you know any stackexchange site about law?

Comment: @sovler Not sure, see: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: This was a ruling in a Federal court; the judge at this stage of trial was only called upon to determine whether there was substantial likelihood that the NSA program would be found unconstitutional.

Answer (score 0):

Courts of course decide upon matters, and supreme courts of course decide upon the constitutionality of things with regard to the constitution of the jurisdiction in which they are the supreme court.

With this case being about the US Federal Constitution, only the US Supreme Court can rule something unconstitutional.

However, a lesser court and/or a less full hearing can in some cases address whether something is likely in breech of a law or constitution.

In this case, the plaintiffs were bringing a case to the US Supreme Court, but had sought a preliminary injunction in the District Court of the District of Columbia.

The finding included:

> the Court concludes that the plaintiffs have standing to challenge the constitutionality of the Government’s bulk collection and querying of phone record metadata, that they have demonstrated a substantial likelihood of success on the merits of their Fourth Amendment claim, and that they will suffer irreparable harm absent preliminary injunctive relief.

In the above, the "Fourth Amendment" refers to the Fourth Amendment to the US Constitution (prohibiting unreasonable searches and seizures) and states that they have "demonstrated a substantial **likelihood**" of winning the case on that basis.

It was this that the newspaper headline summarised as "likely unconstitutional". This is in headline-grammar that omits much that would make a grammatical sentence in other cases; outside of a headline or title we'd expect it to be something more like "It is likely that the NSA phone program is unconstitutional".

Comment: Not quite. Any court can find an action to be unconstitutional; SCOTUS is the ultimate court of appeal. And this ruling was issued in the Federal court where the trial has been brought; but it is very probable that whatever the outcome there it will be appealed all the way to SCOTUS.

Comment: @StoneyB you are indeed correct. The District Court only had to rule on likelihood as it was for a preliminary hearing, but you are right that it could well have found a fourth amendment breech if the case was one where that was relevant. In this case though, there is a more involved argument about a Supreme Court precedent, that almost certainly is a matter for that court alone.

Comment: But only a few cases are appealed all the way to SCOTUS, and SCOTUS takes only a handful of those. Only SCOTUS can overturn its precedents, but every court must follow them.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm pretty sure this one is going to SCOTUS. And if it wasn't going there for its hearing, the only way I could see it not being appealed by which ever side lost at each level all the way up is if the plaintiffs died.

Comment: Or Congress changes the law before it gets to SCOTUS, which would probably make the matter moot.

Answer (score -2):

The use of 'likely' refers to the opinion by pundits, legal experts, and significantly, lower courts.  Whereas, something may be adjudged 'unconstitutional', it is not unconstitutional till it is reviewed by SCOTUS.

The Supreme Court has the power to overrule/confirm or even withhold judgement on decisions made by lower courts, and SCOTUS judges have the final determinant on the interpretation of the US Constitution.

Thus the statement "NSA phone program likely unconstitutional." is just an inconsequential **opinion** -ergo, meaningless